# How to upgrade an infusion in an item in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have an ascended piece of equipment with a defensive infusion slot, which currently contains a +3 agony resistance infusion. I have now crafted a +6 agony infusion and I would like to replace the current one with this new, better one.

However, agony infusions can only be applied to **unused** defensive infusion slots. How can I replace an existing defensive infusion with a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> agony infusions can only be applied to **unused** defensive infusion slots.

This is not true. Just like upgrades, infusions can overwrite other infusions normally. The problem you are having is that you are trying to place a +6 Agony Infusion into a Defensive Infusion Slot, which is impossible. [+X Agony Infusions](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Agony_Infusion) can *only* be placed in agony infusion slots (emphasis mine):

> An Agony Infusion is a type of Infusion upgrade item that **can be added to the agony infusion slot** of any infused ascended rings or backpieces to increase your Agony Resistance.

If you want to place agony infusions in a defensive, offensive, or utility infusion slot, you have to use things like [Versatile Simple Infusion](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Versatile_Simple_Infusion). The [Versatile Basic Infusion](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Versatile_Basic_Infusion) you are likely using currently is one of these so-called Omni infusions.

See the [Infusion](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Infusion) page for more info.

---

That said, if you want to extract your infusions, which is particularly useful for upgrading the +X Agony infusions to a higher level, you can buy an [Infusion Extraction Device](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Infusion_Extraction_Device). It is sold by [Dessa's Crewe](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dessa's_Krewe), who is only reachable after unlocking [Fractal Mastery Level I](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Central_Tyria_mastery_tracks#Fractal_Attunement).

Comment: The same vendor also sells [Versatile Simple Infusions](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Versatile_Simple_Infusion_%28Masterwork%29) with +7 Agony resistance, the highest you can place in non-agony infusion slots.